# How to perform merge operation on spark Dataframe?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I have spark dataframe `mainDF` and `deltaDF` both with a matching schema.

Content of the mainDF is as follows:

```
id | name | age
1  | abc  | 23
2  | xyz  | 34
3  | pqr  | 45
```

Content of `deltaDF` is as follows:

```
id | name | age
1  | lmn  | 56
4  | efg  | 37
```

I want to merge `deltaDF` with `mainDF` based on value of `id`. So if my `id` already exists in `mainDF` then the record should be updated and if `id` doesn't exist then the new record should be added. So the resulting data frame should be like this:

```
id | name | age
1  | lmn  | 56
2  | xyz  | 34
3  | pqr  | 45
4  | efg  | 37
```

This is my current code and it is working:

```
  val updatedDF = mainDF.as("main").join(deltaDF.as("delta"),$"main.id" === $"delta.id","inner").select($"main.id",$"main.name",$"main.age")
 mainDF= mainDF.except(updateDF).unionAll(deltaDF)
```

However here I need to explicitly provide list columns again in the select function which feels like overhead to me. Is there any other better/cleaner approach to achieve the same?

Comment: have you tried `join()` ?

Comment: It's not really in line with your question, but you can also do a union with a timestamp (a dummy one if you have none) and drop lines with duplicate id and older timestamp.

Comment: why you didnt use union ?

Comment: I am using union. Forgot to add that code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you don't want to provide the list of columns explicitly, you can map over the original DF's columns, something like:

```
.select(mainDF.columns.map(c => $"main.$c" as c): _*)
```

BTW you can do this without a `union` after the `join`: you can use `outer` join to get records that don't exist in both DFs, and then use `coalesce` to "choose" the non-null value prefering `deltaDF`'s values. So the complete solution would be something like:

```
val updatedDF = mainDF.as("main")
  .join(deltaDF.as("delta"), $"main.id" === $"delta.id", "outer")
  .select(mainDF.columns.map(c => coalesce($"delta.$c", $"main.$c") as c): _*)

updatedDF.show
// +---+----+---+
// | id|name|age|
// +---+----+---+
// |  1| lmn| 56|
// |  3| pqr| 45|
// |  4| efg| 37|
// |  2| xyz| 34|
// +---+----+---+
```

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this by using `dropDuplicates` and specifying on wich column you don't want any duplicates.

Here's a working code :

```
 val a = (1,"lmn",56)::(2,"abc",23)::(3,"pqr",45)::Nil
 val b = (1,"opq",12)::(5,"dfg",78)::Nil

 val df1 = sc.parallelize(a).toDF
 val df2 = sc.parallelize(b).toDF

 df1.unionAll(df2).dropDuplicates("_1"::Nil).show()

+---+---+---+
| _1| _2| _3|
+---+---+---+
|  1|lmn| 56|
|  2|abc| 23|
|  3|pqr| 45|
|  5|dfg| 78|
+---+---+---+
```

Comment: It doesn't work because it's randomly deleting one duplicate record, in merge scenario the latest record has to be picked ignoring the old one

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing so: pyspark implementation

```
updatedDF = mainDF.alias(“main”).join(deltaDF.alias(“delta”), main.id == delta.id,"left")
upsertDF = updatedDF.where(“main.id IS not null").select("main.*")
unchangedDF = updatedDF.where(“main.id IS NULL”).select("delta.*")
finalDF = upsertDF.union(unchangedDF)
```